# fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I'm using laravel and I want to send a fake email to my mailtrap, but this what I have:

> fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

, or another error says:

> Expected response code 250 but got an empty response.

and sometimes it works only once and returns to the same ERROR
Please help me, I am tired of this thing

this is my code for smtp

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=**********
MAIL_PASSWORD=***********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=test@test.com
```

and I'm using XAMPP

Answer (score 1):

The fwrite() function was failed and most likely the remote host does not allow the action hence reject it by disconnecting the connection.

Most probably you didn't supply the `MAIL_ENCRYPTION` option.